# How to make the page recognize phone/tablets from desktops ? (without media queries)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was looking at a list of the different resolutions of phones and tablets for CSS designers and I realized that some phones have huge resolutions and some tablets even have bigger resolution than most computers.

Now here's my problem: I have a little gadget on my page that makes the logo move a bit toward the mouse. It makes a nice effect on computers but would be useless on tablets and phones (and probably be a problem as I'm not sure whether or not the logo is properly centered originally without the mouse). I managed to disable it and replace it with the normal logo on small phones with media queries but is there a way for the page (through Jquery or whatever) to recognize if the user is on tablet and thus modify the page accordingly?

Comment: You can target with useragent string (not that accurate) or make use of CSS pixel-ratio media queries to target high res devices

Comment: Define "tablet". My laptop has a touchscreen _and_ a mouse. That being said, there's [growing support for media queries aroundinput capabilities](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-hover-pointer/)

Comment: So you actually want to detect **mouse**, don't you? You don't want mouseless computers and you don't mind tablets with mouse. (Or maybe just rewrite the feature so it doesn't break if mouse never shows up.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a script from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. Its fairly easy to use. Also see: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)